# vscode doesn't start on Archlinux after update

Tags: arch-linux

I have Archlinux with Erbium (node v12.22.12) node package and installed vscode via yay (visual-studio-code-bin).

Everything was working until version `visual-studio-code-bin-1.66.2-1-x86_64` now there are two updates (`visual-studio-code-bin-1.66.2-2-x86_64` and `visual-studio-code-bin-1.67.0-1-x86_64`) after this version and neither are working (nothing happens when clicking on vscode icon). Code doesn't start from command line too.

I have electron `v18.2.1`

I have uninstalled NVM but it didn't fix the issue.

I cannot find `vscode` logs path too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `code --verbose` from the terminal - it should print a startup log on stdout.